# Send a quick response to a server and then process code

Tags: php, webhooks

The context is as follows, I have a relatively large code inside a webhook, I receive data from a server and need to process it. The problem is that this processing takes time due to some complex SQL, and if it exceeds 5000ms, it gives a timeout to their server. So as soon as I receive the request I need to send them a response. How do I do this with PHP?

I've already tried

```
http_response_code(200);
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: 0');
ob_end_flush();
flush();

ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: Typically nowadays, you'd create an entry in a job queue and then immediately respond to the caller. A second process would run continually in the background, pulling jobs out of the queue and processing them.

Comment: How can I respond to the caller? http_response_code(200) didn't work

Comment: 200 should be the default that is already being provided by your web server, you shouldn't have to do anything special, and you shouldn't need any of the code you posted. The only thing you might need to do is output a Content-Type header if (for example) you're going to give the caller some JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, there is not specific enough information about the use case. however I will give a few examples and hopefully this assists you on your journey. Lets go through a typical planning cycle keeping in mind that processing will take some time longer than a single post request will allow.

**Store and forget**

In some cases where you are only receiving data, you can store the post variables with an insert query and send a received message. This will allow you to tell the requester their information has been received, downside is we are not giving much further data... lets keep expanding...

**Store and check back**

since we are likely going to want the requester to follow up with a status update we should send them a json array response after the initial insert query containing an ID or key they can use to request a status update. We would initially store the variables in the database in a "to be processed" table. then have a cron running that checks the "to be processed" table periodically and updates the Processed boolean (or other variable) on that table to allow the system to quickly tell when things have been dealt with.
the client would then send another request periodically to quickly check the status of their request. This could be further expanded to allow a nice UI effect with status variables being changed. for example on the client side they could watch the status change through "sending", "queued", "processed", "complete" and then show the processed information when the status has reached the complete status.

From the clients point of view, they are getting quick feedback and updates as it goes. you could even go further and estimate the wait time and sending that back in each of your status update responses by calculating the average time to complete a single entry and calling a COUNT variable from the database where the status is not complete and the id is less than the requesters entry.

Hope this helps :)